# AngularJS: Bind back to array of inputs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, input

I have an `array` of `string` that I want to bind to an array of `input`s:

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="form-group" ng-repeat="remark in trip.remarks track by $index">
    <label>Remarque {{$index + 1}}:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="remark"></textarea>
</li>
<hr>
</ul>
<button ng-click="addRemark()" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100%">Ajouter</button>`
```

In my controller I have already initialized the `trip` object, and the binding does happen, but when I edit the data through the `textarea` nothing changes in the `trip` object.

The is how my controller is coded:

```
$scope.trip = productService.getCurrentTrip();

$scope.addRemark = function () {
    $scope.trip.remarks.push("");
}
```

It seem the binding is happening only from the controller to the view, also when I click `addRemark` button a new `textarea` does appear. So can anyone tell me how can I bind back to the controller?

NB:

1)I also tried to bind to this controller using `ng-model="trip.remarks[$index]"` but no use.

2) I have other fields in `trip` object that are binded and working two-ways

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of prototypal inheritance which you can further explore [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/3582863).

In your code snippet here:

```
ng-repeat="remark in trip.remarks track by $index"
```

Ng-repeat is creating a child scope for every remark in your trip object, and since remark is a primitive type, any modifications to it are getting hidden/shadowed and only modifying the child scope. The solution is therefore to utilize the "." notation as lzagkaretos mentioned, or bind your ng-model to an object reference as opposed to the primitive (string).

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 should work. See [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RS08fbA0NQRrTp59rHmm?p=preview).

```
ng-model="trip.remarks[$index]"
```

If it does not work for you, please check the `trip` object structure, maybe it is not as clear as something like `{"remarks":["remark 1","remark 2d"]}`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the textarea NgModel is pointing to the same reference. To do so, create an array of objects where you only edit one value of that object.

Here's an example:

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("myCtrl", function($scope){

$scope.trip = {};
$scope.trip.remarks = [
{"name": "1", "value": "hello world 1"},
{"name": "2", "value": "hello world 2"},
{"name": "3", "value": "hello world 3"},
];

$scope.test = function(){
  alert($scope.trip.remarks[0].value + " | " + $scope.trip.remarks[1].value + " | " + $scope.trip.remarks[2].value);
};

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">

ul>
<li class="form-group" ng-repeat="remark in trip.remarks track by $index">
    <label>Remarque {{$index + 1}}:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="remark.value"></textarea>
</li>
<hr>
</ul>
<button ng-click="test()" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100%">Ajouter</button>

</div>
```